# is it possible to scan all carrier frequencies with Android?

Tags: android, gsm, cellular-network

I am trying to get the Received Signal Strength(RSS) of all channels using Android phone. But currently I can only get Neighboring Cell information. Is it possible to get RSS of all absolute radio-frequency channel numbers (ARFCNs)?

Comment: Base band of your phone has a limitation that only show scan of cell towers that their MCC and MNC is same as your simcard. For example if you have a simcard of a specific carrier with MCC=432 and MNC=20 your base band only show celltowers with MCC=432 and MNC=20 , no other cell towers related to other carriers .

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a method to tell your mobile to tune your antenna to those specific channels, the mobile will not scan those.  Typically, it won't scan other channels unless told to by the base station.

Comment: how I can get scan of cell towers of all carriers? I only get scan of cell towers related to my sim card. I want cell towers of all carriers